# Accessing columns of a matrix using the entries of another matrix R

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following two matrices:

```
routes
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
    1  a  b  c      
    2  a  d  c  e   
    3  a  b         
    4  a  c  e  d  b

coords
              a   b   c   d e
x             2 -5.0  1 4.00 5
y             6  7.0 -8 1.00 5
slope         3 -1.4 -8 0.25 1
sector-number 2  3.0  6 0.00 1
```

I am trying to access the columns of coords with entries of routes. 
For example given `route[2,3]` which is c, I want `coords[route[2,3]]` to give me the entries of the column named c. However it does not do this, even though `coords["c"]` gives the desired result.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are these matrices or data.frame?  What is your expected output?  Your object name is `routes` and not `route`?  It is working for me with `coords[routes[2,3]]`

Comment: Following akrun's comment, you are probably working with data.frames, in which case, the route vectors are factors (use `sapply(routes, class)` to check), not characters. If this is true, then `coords[as.character(route[2,3])]` should work.